# Best way to read and write Excel with no dependencies on Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: c#, excel, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I want to read and write excel file with extensions: .xls and .xlsx (Generated from any office version i.e. Office 2003, Office 2016).

I have read and written Excel with office interop, it is working fine at local environment but once I hosted on **Azure Cloud Service Worker Role**, it is not working(Need office interop dependency).

Please suggest me best way to read and write excel with no dependencies in Azure environment?

Comment: Have you treid EPPLus lib ? http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have you marked the Office Interop dlls as copy local? You would also need to consider licensing requirements of in these dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml).

It's probably easiest to start with ClosedXML, which builds upon OpenXML, and makes a lot of tasks much simpler.

If ClosedXML does not work for older versions, you can try [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

I haven't tried it myself, but a lot of people recommend it.

Not sure about the support for Office 2003 though. You'll have to check for that.

Comment: Thanks, I have create demo and read file using OpenXml and ExcelDataReader both reads file on Azure WorkerRole. OpenXml does not read older version i.e. .xls extension files. ExcelDataReader works with older versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [FreeSpire](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html#.V-JKg5grKUk). It works perfectly for .xlsx but has some limitations for .xls

**Edit:**

Our use case was to Password-Protect the excel file. So, we achieved this using the following code:

```
Workbook book = new Workbook();
book.LoadFromFile(@"E:\Work\Documents\Sample.xlsx");
//Protect Workbook
book.Protect("abc-123");
//Save
book.SaveToFile("Output.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
```

You can download the dll [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81c33294-eee9-4683-9cee-a5714cfebf34)

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged. Request you to add some code sample showing how you used this library.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for pointing out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, FreeSprire.XLS works file on Azure and it reads older and newer versions of excel.